# Android Input method service client application

Tags: android, service, android-softkeyboard

I am developing an custom keyboard/Input method service as given bellow

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/creating-input-method.html

In this I want to know which client application is using my keyboard? Like user is typing a message with my keyboard or writing an email or any other app like whatsapp..

Is there any way? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it using this code

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
                .getPackageName();
```